How and what is the use Lambda in mustache template using java
I have been Tasked to use mustache template engine for the sole purpose of rendering templates while researching on how to use this i have stumbled across lambdas which i still quiet can't catch
For example in the official mustache documentations it is mentioned usage is
Template:

{{#wrapped}}{{name}} is awesome.{{/wrapped}}

Hash:

{
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped": function(text) {
    return "<b>" + text + "</b>"
  }
}

Output:

<b> Willy is awesome.</b>

So the expected output is  Willy is awesome  but I can't get the same output here is what I passed
{
    "tId": "function",
    "data": {
        "name": "Vishnu",
        "wrapped": "function(text) { return \"<b>\" + text + \"</b>\"; }",
}
}

Even though the template is all same I get just "Vishnu is awesome" with exception of the tags. What am i suppose to get exactly ? the text in bold or the text with tags
Am I missing something here ? How and what is the working of lambdas in this templating engine ?
In the similar fashion the other example in same documentation doesn't work
Template:

* {{time.hour}}
* {{today}}

Hash:

{
  "year": 1970,
  "month": 1,
  "day": 1,
  "time": function() {
    return {
      "hour": 0,
      "minute": 0,
      "second": 0
    }
  },
  "today": function() {
    return "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}"
  }
}

Output:

* 0
* 1970-1-1

The output that i get is function() {return ("{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}";)}
When I pass JSON as   \ "time": "function() { return {\"hour\": 0,\"minute\": 0,      \"second\": 0}  };", "today": "function() {return (\"{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}\";)}" \
Reffered documentation : https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html
In some documentations for e.g this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-mustache-js/ mentions that

Lambdas are used to transform data before it is inserted into the template. A lambda is a function that takes a string as input and returns a string as output.

UPDATE 1 :
Most Solutions pointed out that I am referring to a JS based mustache template doc so I have striked it
UPDATE 2
In the Intro to Mustache the example for lambda is still vague. I was able to get the tasks listed but I am still unable to get the lambda function to work. I am trying to pass the following JSON as input
{
    "tId": "test",
    "data": {
        "todos": [
            {
               "handleDone" : "handleDone",
                "title": "Task 1",
                "doneSince": 5,
                "done" : true
            },
            {
               "handleDone" : "handleDone",
                "title": "Task 1",
                "doneSince": 5,
                "done" : true
            },
            {
                "handleDone" : "handleDone",
                "title": "Task 1",
                "doneSince": 5,
                "done" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}

and the code
if (templateId.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {

                        Object doneSinceValue = value;

                        Map<Object, Object> templateData2 = new HashMap<>();
                        templateData2.put(key, handleDone);
                        Mustache mustache = mustacheFactory.compile(new StringReader(dataRcvd.trim()), "main");
                        mustache.execute(writer, templateData2).flush();

                    }



// Changed the code 
   Function<String, String> handleDone = (obj) -> done ? String.format("<small>Done %s minutes ago<small>", obj) : "";
    }

What am I doing wrong ? Any comments suggestion (I have attached the completed code for reference)
The Service Layer of the app where the implementation exists Github link
What does this mean ? I would like a simplfied explanation of the same
Also i need to understand how to pass this lambda in JSON ?
Any help is highly appreciated

Please show not only the template, but also how you call and what data is passed in. It seems you are passing JS function instead of Java lambda.

@lesiak I have added the github link for my app

The tutorial article you link to is MustacheJS. Java isn’t JS.

Indeed your wrapped is just a String. MustacheJava simply ignores it. BTW please post your question with a minimal reproducible example, external links are not welcome. This is even more true for an external link to an app without a pointer to the right file.

@ThomasKläger I don't think you are correct, Mustache.java supports passing functions as data

@Lesiak I stand corrected and retracted my comment

TLDR: The example clearly says you need to pass a lambda, but you are passing a string instead.
Get a proper intro for mustache.java. Mixing concepts from JS and Java is likely to confuse you. I find the Introduction to Mustache a good start.
Both mustache.js and mustache.java support passing functions as data.
In case of Java:
Function<String, String> wrapped = (input) -> "<b>" +input + "</b>";
Map<String, Object> data = Map.of(
        "name", "Willy",
        "wrapped", wrapped
);

MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache m = mf.compile("example.mustache");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
m.execute(writer, data).flush();
String output = writer.toString();

In your code, you are passing a string instead:
Map<String, Object> data = Map.of(
        "name", "Willy",
        "wrapped", "Your code for JS function"
);

MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache m = mf.compile("example.mustache");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
m.execute(writer, data).flush();
String output = writer.toString();

Mustache silently ignores the fact that the passed in object is not a function.

Is this applicable when I use JSON to pass data if so how would the JSON look ?
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped":  ?
  }
} ```
Or do Need not pass "wrapped" at all ?
This is the confusion for the todo example in the mustache docs as well

I updated the question as well any help is appreciated

You must pass a lambda. In your updated question handledDone is a function returning a lambda. You should pass this lambda as data, and not call it (do not call apply)

In terms of JSON as data source - you must deserialize the JSON string. In JS you can have function code in string and transform it to function using eval, but it is unsafe and discouraged. In Java, you cannot transform string containing code to a working lambda - you can have a name of the function in JSON string but you must pass an actual lambda to mustache

So i passed the json "data": {         "name" : "willy",         "wrapped" : "wrapped"     }
and got the desired output but the same doesn't work of the todo instead of the message the doneSince value is displayed for all placeholders any suggestions ?

You are, again, passing string instead of lambda.
